# Adding attachment to system message with getMailer and composeFromKey

Tags: plugin-development

I have already created a new system message called `after_new_submission` -- all good there.

Now, I'm trying to use that system message AND add an attachment.

Here's what I've tried below, but the error is:

`($mailer) must be of type ?yii\\mail\\MailerInterface, craft\\mail\\Message given`

My code:

```
// create new Message from PDF string
$message = new Message();
$message->attach($this->actionPdf($entry->uid, true), [
    'fileName' => $this->pdfName,
    'contentType' => 'application\pdf'
]);  

// create new Event for mailer
$event = new UserEvent([
    'user' => $user
]);
$userEvent = $event->user;

// send mail
Craft::$app
->getMailer()
->composeFromKey('after_new_submission', [
    'submission' => $body // 
])
->setTo($userEvent)
->send($message);
```

Is something like this possible?